# UIButton with both Touch Up Inside and Touch Repeat?

Tags: ios, uibutton, touch-up-inside

What's the best way to get a button to be capable of both a `Touch Up Inside` action and a `Touch Down Repeat` action?  Kind of like the Home button on an iPhone: one click goes to the home screen, but two rapid clicks opens the multitasking bar.  Right now my button has both methods hooked up, but the `Touch Up Inside` method (unsurprisingly) gets called before the `Touch Down Repeat` can happen.

I can come up with a few ways I might pull this off (having the Touch Up Inside method wait a second to see if another click comes before executing, having a second button move invisibly into place after the first click, etc) but they all seem kind of hack-y and open to performance losses and bugs.  I found the `tapCount` property, but it's for UITouch instead of UIButton, so `if([_buttonAddItems tapCount] > 1) {} else if([_buttonAddItems tapCount] == 1)`, which seems like it would be the most efficient way of doing it, doesn't work.

Is there a best-practice for this sort of thing?  Or if not, does anyone have a preferred way of getting this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try disconnecting both touch events from your button, and hook two tap gesture recognizers to it instead. Here is a [link to an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8876299/335858) that explains how to set up two gesture recognizers so that one of them recognizes a single tap, and the other one recognizes a double tap:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(doSingleTap)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1; 
[myButton addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(doDoubleTap)];
doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2; 
[myButton  addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
// This is the "secret sauce":
[singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];
```

Comment: I've never played with GestureRecognizers before, but that looks like exactly what I'm looking for, thanks!