# why is performSelector not present in swift

Tags: ios, swift

apparently the following is not available in swift anymore:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(onFlip) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
```

why is this the case if the following is still present:

```
NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget(self, selector: singleTapSelector, object: nil)
```

doesn't nsobject.cancel work with performSelector? why have the cancel functionality but not the perform functionality?

Comment: Your first line is incorrect. It needs to be `let singleTapSelector = Selector("singleTap")`

Comment: I checked the NSObject documentation and according to that the method is available. Though code completion does not show it. Strange.

Comment: I inserted `performSelector(Selector("a"), withObject:nil, afterDelay:1.0)` and the compiler fails with "not available". But the alt-click shows the help for it telling "available in 10.10". Smells like a bug (there are plenty already).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(delay, target: self, selector: "onFlip", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

instead. No idea why the other one is not available.

Comment: by the way, can I use the cancelPrevious... with this NSTimer call?

Answer (score 10):

## We can easily *unlock* these methods in Swift 1.x! Yay!

These methods from the **`perfromSelector`** family actually exist in Swift but they were artificially hidden (by design, I think) prior Swift 2.0. They can be unveiled using swizzling and some Objective-C runtime hacks right in Swift.

Just add this extension file `NSObject+PerformSelector.swift` and prefix all calls with  symbol.

In your case the code:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(onFlip) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
```

can be rewritten in Swift like this:

```
self.performSelector("onFlip", withObject: nil, afterDelay: 0.3)
```

With using this magical category (class extension):
`NSObject+PerformSelector.swift`

```
import Foundation

private var dispatchOnceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0

private var selectors: [Selector] = [
    "performSelector:",
    "performSelector:withObject:",
    "performSelector:withObject:withObject:",
    "performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:inModes:",
    "performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:",
]

private func swizzle() {
    dispatch_once(&dispatchOnceToken) {
        for selector: Selector in selectors {
            let selector = Selector("\(selector)")
            let method = class_getInstanceMethod(NSObject.self, selector)

            class_replaceMethod(
                NSObject.self,
                selector,
                method_getImplementation(method),
                method_getTypeEncoding(method)
            )
        }
    }
}

extension NSObject {

    func performSelector(selector: Selector) -> AnyObject? {
        swizzle()
        return self.performSelector(selector)
    }

    func performSelector(selector: Selector, withObject object: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject? {
        swizzle()
        return self.performSelector(selector, withObject: object)
    }

    func performSelector(selector: Selector, withObject object1: AnyObject?, withObject object2: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject? {
        swizzle()
        return self.performSelector(selector, withObject: object1, withObject: object2)
    }

    func performSelector(selector: Selector, withObject object: AnyObject?, afterDelay delay: NSTimeInterval, inModes modes: [AnyObject?]?) {
        swizzle()
        self.performSelector(selector, withObject: object, afterDelay: delay, inModes: modes)
    }

    func performSelector(selector: Selector, withObject object: AnyObject?, afterDelay delay: NSTimeInterval) {
        swizzle()
        self.performSelector(selector, withObject: object, afterDelay: delay)
    }

}
```

Comment: Why the rocket symbol?

Comment: Because Emoji is fun and we can use it in Swift! My first intension was `` banana symbol but I decided to switch to more conformist-like `` rocket symbol.

Of course any another prefix can be used.

Comment: Yes, but why is a prefix even needed?

Comment: We have to use a prefix because otherwise Xcode reports an error: `Method 'performSelector' with Objective-C selector 'performSelector:' conflicts with previous declaration with the same Objective-C selector`.

Comment: Honestly, I think that allowing emoji was a most silly idea. So instead of typing via keyboard I have to click around in annoying tables. This isn't funny at all. The best would be to say it's silly.

Comment: From Swift prospective, emojis is not a point at all, the point is that you can use any character from any language whatever you want. Actually, I may have hardware emoji keyboard as somebody may have greek keyboard.

Answer (score 5):

```
func performFlipOnDelay() {
  let delayInSeconds = 1.0
  let delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delayInSeconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
  dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
     onFlip();
  }
}
```

Another round about answer would be the above using GCD to add a delay time for an action to be performed

Answer (score 3):

Taking the answer from Thomas Kilian a step further, primarily to enhance readability on calling clients, I've defined a swift utility, TimerUtil.swift, defining a facade on NSTimer for this particular usecase:

```
import Foundation

/**
 * Convenience function to make a single timer scheduling more readable.
 */
public func invoke( selector:Selector, on target:AnyObject, afterDelay delay:NSTimeInterval ) {

    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval( delay, target: target, selector: selector, userInfo: nil, repeats: false )
}
```

Then your code can simply call:

```
invoke( "onFlip", on:self, afterDelay:0.3 )
```

which more or less resembles performSelector:withObject:afterDelay

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4
use This to Handle These Types of Warning!

```
perform(#selector(yourMethodName), with: nil, afterDelay: 0, inModes: [])
```