# Why and how does UIPanGestureRecognizer mute UISwipeGestureRecognizer while UITapGestureRecognizers don't mute each other by default?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

In the doc [Coordinating Multiple Gesture Recognizers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/coordinating_multiple_gesture_recognizers), it says:

> UIKit normally allows the recognition of only one gesture at a time on
>   a single view. ...  For example, **in a view that contains both pan and swipe gesture recognizers, swipes are never recognized**.

With that being said, there are also some exceptions. For example, in a view with two `UITapGestureRecognizer`s, the actions of [both will get fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876202/uitapgesturerecognizer-single-tap-and-double-tap).

There's the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` method `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith:)` comes into play **externally**. But how can the system built-in gesture recognizers, such as `UITapGestureRecognizer`, decide **internally** whether or not to work with other recognizers? Or, is there any difference between *continuous gesture recognizers* and *discrete gesture recognizers* as regards the behavior?

Comment: Hi! Had you tried to see what is the behaviour when you use this delegate: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1620006-shouldrequirefailure  (like, if pan fails do the swipe)

Comment: @RenataFaria Sorry for not reading your comment carefully in the first place! I thought it was a link to the doc of the delegate. I think the method you suggested is the key to the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are two interesting methods of `UIGestureRecognizer` in the decision process, in which gesture recognizers may be "prevented":

- [`canPrevent(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1620008-canprevent)
- [`canBePrevented(by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1620003-canbeprevented)

By debugging subclasses of `UITapGestureRecognizer`, `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` and `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, I found that:

- A "double tap" recognizer will prevent a "single tap" recognizer, but NOT vice versa
- A pan recognizer will prevent a swipe recognizer

When there are multiple gesture recognizers, the first one that recognizes its gesture will render other recognizers into `.failed`, by default.

That explains the observed behavior.