# How to if double tap else single tap UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am trying to recognise if users tap a single tap once or double-tap

```
if (gestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired == 2 ){
            print("Double")

        }else{print("single")
}
```

Thank you for you advice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UITapGestureRecognizer - single tap and double tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876202/uitapgesturerecognizer-single-tap-and-double-tap)

Comment: You aren't the first to ask this question.  Not even the second...

Answer (score 1):

you will need to use two gesture recognizers for this . One to capture the single tap gestures and another for double taps .

Sample code :

```
let singleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didPressPartButton))
singleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
view.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapGesture)

let doubleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didDoubleTap))
doubleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
view.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGesture)
```